# Remove background color css while hovering a button

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angular and html.

[image]
In the above image, you can see for the first icon, some background color is coming while hovering.

I tried

```css
.sidemenuitm {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.lineheight {
  line-height: 13px;
}

.btn-change {
  border-right: #b41414 3px solid;
}

.selectedmenu {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: black;
  border-left: solid rgb(214, 208, 208) 1px;
  border-top: solid rgb(214, 208, 208) 1px;
  border-bottom: solid rgb(214, 208, 208) 1px;
}

.backupicon {
  width: 85px;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="element.id=='3'" class="sidemenuitm lineheight" [routerLink]="element.url" routerLinkActive="selectedmenu btn-change" [matTooltip]="menuname ? element.tooltip : ''" matTooltipPosition="right" [matTooltipClass]="'tooltipwidth'">
  <button mat-button [disabled]="is_accessible" class="backupicon" (click)="selectcomp(i)">
    <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">{{element.iconname}}</mat-icon>
    <div *ngIf="menuname">{{element.name}}</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

But no luck

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Please make an reproducible HTML. Image does not help us  to help you.

Comment: I've made your code into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), but of course it doesn't look quite like your screenshot since we don't have the data. If you can get the rendered HTML, that would be ideal. What you can do is, once you get the screen looking like what you want, right-click the button, say, and select Inspect Element. Navigate to a suitable wrapping element and right-click that in the Elements pane. Select Copy > Copy as outerHTML. Then paste it here.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps below

```
<button class="button" (mouseenter)="buttonHover = true"  (mouseleave)="buttonHover = false" [ngclass]="(buttonHover)? 'hover' : '' '> ... </button>
```

Add variable to ButtonComponent.ts

```
export class BasicComponent{
    buttonHover = false;

    ...
}
```

Update CSS as below

```
button {
  background: coral;
}

.button.hover {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: A very late-1990s "DHTML" solution. Interesting.

Comment: I'm very interested with angular DOM events, most of the time with the CSS BEM manipulation I had to follow the above manner...

Comment: In my opinion, this should be able to be done with just CSS. `button:hover` works fine, and if so many layers of abstraction have been added to the code that it no longer does, it may be time to rethink those layers.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.button {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
}
.button:hover{
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Link Button</a>
```

Comment: button can be declared as any other HTML element in CSS, without . witch is used only for class, and I don't see any .button class in his HTML markup.

Comment: When providing code, it is best to use the OP's own example HTML and CSS and modify it to meet their needs. That way, any issues with overriding styles will be accounted for. Also, adding an explanation of code is always a good idea, so that people who come by with the same question can benefit from the answer.

Comment: Perhaps there is a clash with the css of the materialize classes. Maybe try !important.